# Optional Sampling Theorem Application on a Martingale

Tags: stochastic-processes, martingales

I'm struggling to figure out how to apply the optional sampling theorem to this problem.  Here's the problem verbatim (it's problem 5.7 out of Lawler's *Introduction to Stochastic Properties)*:

*Consider a biased random walk on the integers with probability $p < \frac{1}{2}$ of moving to the right and probability $1 - p$ of moving to the left.  Let $S_n$ be the value at time $n$ and assume that $S_0 = a$, where $0 < a < N$.*

*a) Show that $M_n = [(1-p)/p]^{S_n}$ is a martingale.*

*b) Let $T$ be the first time that the random walk reaches $0$ or $N$, i.e.,*
$$T = min\{n : S_n = 0\ or\ N\}$$
*Use optional sampling on the martingale $M_n$ to compute $P\{S(T) = 0\}$.*

I'm nearly positive I did part $a)$ correctly.  Here's my work for that:

I need to show that $E(M_{n+1}|F_n) = M_n.$

$$E(M_{n+1}|F_n) =  E((\frac{1-p}{p})^{S_{n+1}}|F_n)=p(\frac{1-p}{p})^{S_n+1} + (1-p)(\frac{1-p}{p})^{S_n-1}$$
$$=p(\frac{1-p}{p})^{S_n}(\frac{1-p}{p}) + (1-p)(\frac{1-p}{p})^{S_n}(\frac{p}{1-p})$$
$$=(\frac{1-p}{p})^{S_n}(p + (1-p)) = (\frac{1-p}{p})^{S_n} = M_n$$

Since $E(M_{n+1}|F_n) = M_n$, I have shown that it is a martingale.

Part $b)$ is where I get tripped up.  The martingale is bounded and $P\{T < \infty\} = 0$, so I know that I can use the optional sampling theorem and $E(M_T) = E(M_0)$.  I just don't know what exactly I can do.  Any advice for a novice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have either $S(T)=0$ or $S(T)=N$. Thus you have

$$\Bbb{P}(S(T)=0) + \Bbb{P}(S(T)=N) = 1.$$

On the other hand, the application of optional sampling theorem gives

$$\begin{align*}
\left(\frac{1-p}{p}\right)^{a}
&= \Bbb{E}M_0 = \Bbb{E}M_{T} \\
&= \left(\frac{1-p}{p}\right)^{0}\Bbb{P}(S(T)=0) + \left(\frac{1-p}{p}\right)^{N}\Bbb{P}(S(T)=N).
\end{align*}$$

Now we have a system of linear equations with respect to $\Bbb{P}(S(T)=0)$ and $\Bbb{P}(S(T)=N)$, thus we obtain the answer by solving this system.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I actually made a typo in my original post.  $M_n = [(1-p)/p]^{S_n}$, not $[(1-p)p]^{S_n}$.  This, however, shouldn't change your answer (aside from changing your $p(1-p)$ terms to $(1-p)/p$).  Either way, this makes perfect sense.  Thank you!

Comment: @JackRadcliffe You're welcome. I also fixed it.

Comment: @SangchulLee, So the $\mathbb{P} (S(T)=0)= 1-\frac{p^N}{p^N + (1-p)^N}- \left(\frac{1-p}{p}\right)^a \cdot \frac{p^N}{p^N + (1-p)^N}$  Is this correct?